# Enable zoom and pan in Coreplot for CPTPieChart

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot, pinchzoom

```
CPTPieChart *pieChart = [[CPTPieChart alloc] init];
pieChart.plotSpace.delegate = self;
pieChart.plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction=YES;
pieChart.labelOffset=-50;
pieChart.dataSource = self;
pieChart.delegate = self;
pieChart.pieRadius = (self.hostView.bounds.size.height * 0.4) / 2;
pieChart.pieInnerRadius=pieChart.pieRadius/2;
pieChart.identifier = graph.title;
pieChart.startAngle = M_PI_4;
pieChart.sliceDirection = CPTPieDirectionClockwise;
```

enabled the userinteraction in plot space my delegate are getting called but the piechart is not zooming and panning.
Get reference to graph

```
CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;
self.hostView.allowPinchScaling=YES;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pie charts don't support pinch-zoom (see [issue #15](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues/15)) or panning. I haven't tried it, but you should be able to use the plot space delegate to adjust the center and/or radius of the plot.